# .htc reference from css file

Tags: asp.net, css, css3pie

I have an .Net application where I want to bring gradient effect to a list item. After googling we can achieve this by using .htc. By .htc reference with css inside aspx everything works fine. But the same styling is copied to some thing stylesheet.css the .htc file is not getting referred. Can any one guide me how to refer .htc from css at behavior.
I have tried all the options I know of. here below I am giving the options I have tried with...

1. behavior: url(c://inetpub//wwwroot//piewebsite//css//PIE.htc');
2. behavior: url(../css/PIE.htc');
3. behavior: url(PIE.htc');
4. behavior: url('http://localhost/piewebsite/PIE.htc');
5. behavior: URL{'~/css/pie.htc');

No Luck with all the options.
Is there any thing I am missing in here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The htc reference has to be relative to the page calling it not the css file. You also won't be able to use the ~ character in your css files as it won't be processed. It will be a modified version of

```
behavior: url('../css/PIE.htc');
```

but I don't know your folder structure so you will have to change it somewhat.

Hope this helps.